# How to return multiple parameters of same type in C (function not void)

Tags: c, parameters, return

The method is defined this way:

```
int func(int *a, int *b){
int x = 0, y = 0;

return <params>;
}
```

I want to return x and y both (x and y are used to increment and decrement as I use a and b in the function). 
When I tried to create an array to return this, it gave me an error: 
returning ‘int *’ from a function with return type ‘int’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Any other way I could do this?

Comment: Isn't the reason for passing pointers is so you can do `*a = x; *b = y;`?

Comment: Best way to do this would be `void func(int *dest1, int *dest2, <params>)` and store returns directly into `dest1` and `dest2` IMO

Comment: @Barmar The reason I want to return x and y, is because I am incrementing them as I use a and b in the function, I apologize for not making that clear

Comment: Then you need more parameters to contain pointers to the output variables.

Comment: `void func(int *a, int *b, int *out1, int *out2)`